# Check if array contains substring?

Tags: kotlin

I've got this array:

```
val array : MutableList<String> =  mutableListOf("laptop on floor", "man is thomas")
```

How do I check if it contains this string: `flo`? (It does, in the first element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code snippet

```
val array : MutableList<String> =  mutableListOf("laptop on floor", "man is thomas")

val doesContain1 = array.indexOfFirst { it.contains("flo") } >= 0
// or
val doesContain2 = array.find { it.contains("flo") } != null
// or
val doesContain3 = array.any { it.contains("flo") }
```

Comment: Of these three options, the third one, using `any`, is definitely the most idiomatic.

Comment: @Sam yes, but the first two also return some extra result